# Why my function of capitalize all first letters return false when is compare with the final result? Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, capitalize

I have this two function that make the first letter of every word capitalize while the rest of the word is in lower case.

I compare the return of every function with the final result desire, but my function return false and the function with map return true. Some one know why?

```js
let str1 = "I'm a little tea pot"
let str2 = "sHoRt AnD sToUt"
let str3 = "HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT"

function titleCase(str) {
  let toArray = str.split(" ")
  let allCapitalize = ""
  for (let x of toArray) {
    allCapitalize += x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase() + " "
  }
  return allCapitalize
}

function titleCaseMap(str) {
  return str.split(" ").map((x) => {
    return x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase()
  }).join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase(str1));
console.log(titleCase(str2));
console.log(titleCase(str3));

console.log(titleCase(str1) === "I'm A Little Tea Pot"); //false
console.log(titleCase(str2) === "Short And Stout"); //false
console.log(titleCase(str3) === "Here Is My Handle Here Is My Spout"); //false

console.log(titleCaseMap(str1))
console.log(titleCaseMap(str2))
console.log(titleCaseMap(str3))

console.log(titleCaseMap(str1) === "I'm A Little Tea Pot"); //true
console.log(titleCaseMap(str2) === "Short And Stout"); //true
console.log(titleCaseMap(str3) === "Here Is My Handle Here Is My Spout"); //true
```

Comment: As mentioned just half a minute before me: Try using ```==``` instead of ```===```. ```===``` also compares datatypes which is why you may be getting an issue.

Comment: Because your result have a space at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `titleCase` function always add an extra space at the end.

You should update it such that the space is not added at the end.

I updated the function to this:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    let toArray = str.split(" ")
    let allCapitalize = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < toArray.length; i++) {
        let x = toArray[i];

        if (i > 0) {
            allCapitalize += " ";
        }

        allCapitalize += x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return allCapitalize
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `titleCase` function is adding a space at the end of the returned lines. You should [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) that off:

```js
let str1 = "I'm a little tea pot"
let str2 = "sHoRt AnD sToUt"
let str3 = "HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT"

function titleCase(str) {
  let toArray = str.split(" ")
  let allCapitalize = ""
  for (let x of toArray) {
    allCapitalize += x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1).toLowerCase() + " "
                                                // Well there's your problem ^
  }
  return allCapitalize.trim();
}

console.log(titleCase(str1));
console.log(titleCase(str2));
console.log(titleCase(str3));

console.log(titleCase(str1) === "I'm A Little Tea Pot"); //false
console.log(titleCase(str2) === "Short And Stout"); //false
console.log(titleCase(str3) === "Here Is My Handle Here Is My Spout"); //false
```

Comment: Was that a [Jamie Hyneman](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/fb/fbdf696d6813c7acf1e429b2b36ed14e990c7331e0d2dc18435b5ca8e23a6bd6.jpg) quote?

Comment: You bet your moustache it is, @DaneBrouwer!